# Open Safari on Mac Client from RDP or Citrix

Tags: macos, safari, rdp, citrix

I have a scenario where I have users accessing our company application either via Citrix or RDP.

The app needs to make a call from within the session to the client pc so it can open a browser for credit card entry.

This is all working okay as I'm using COM to make the call on Windows clients, however I'm not exactly sure how to approach this for Mac.

I believe a start might be able to use AppleScript to open the browser, but not sure on the best way to call the AppleScript. Should I create a C++ app written in xCode.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the shell on the remote Mac all you need to do to open Safari (or other default browser) is to execute `open <URL>`, for example:

```
open http://example.com
```